# TikZ: How to encapsulate shade in node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, circles, nodes

I have this shaded circle:

```
\shade [ball color=black!80!white] (0,0) circle (1);
```

Is it possible to encapsulate it with node style and fixing the circle radius?

Answer (score 5):

You could define a style for nodes using `\tikzstyle`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{ball} = [circle,shading=ball, ball color=black!80!white,
    minimum size=1cm]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [style=ball] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks!. Why can't I have "maximum size" as well?

Comment: I think TikZ doesn't support a maximum size for nodes.

Comment: You can specify text width, text height, text depth and inner sep explicitly. This will define the maximum node size. I don't think it's a good idea, though.

Comment: So how should I ensure that text will be scaled down to fit into node (instead of node scaled up) ?

Comment: For instance with `\resizebox` of the `graphicx` package if needed.