# Drawing Hex Boards

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw a Hex board. I would like to be able to mark each hexagon and mark the size. Being able to control the thickness of the lines would be nice, but it is not something I need to have. Could anyone suggest a simple way of doing this?

Here is a picture of what I had in mind:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/VUkqMYE.png]

**EDIT:** Cmhughes brought up some pointers on making this post better, so here it goes!

I have found very little material to help me through this. However, I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61429/how-to-draw-a-hexagonal-grid-with-numbers-in-the-cells) on the stackexchange forum. I have tried modifying the code (from the first answer) to fit my needs (as shown in the picture), but every time I change something the graph does some very weird things, like creating a large line of hexagons in what appears to be a random direction.

My problem, then, is that I have no idea how I would modify the code to make it a Hex board, rather than a Hex map.

This is the code I am referring to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    hexa/.style={ 
      shape=regular polygon,
      regular polygon sides=6,
      minimum size=1cm,
      draw,
      inner sep=0,
      anchor=south,
      fill=lightgray!85!blue,
      rotate=30
    }
  ]
    \foreach \j in {0,...,5}{%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\end{5+\j} 
      \foreach \i in {0,...,\end}{%
        \node[hexa] (h\i;\j) at ({(\i-\j/2)*sin(60)},{\j*0.75}) {};
      }
    }
    \foreach \j in {0,...,4}{%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\end{9-\j} 
      \foreach \i in {0,...,\end}{%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\k{\j+6}  
        \node[hexa] (h\i;\k) at ({(\i+\j/2-2)*sin(60)},{4.5+\j*0.75}) {};
      }
    }
    \foreach \k in {0,...,10} {%
      \node[circle,red,minimum size=1cm] at (h3;\k) {3;\k};
    }
    \foreach \k in {0,...,10} {%
      \node[circle,blue,minimum size=1cm] at (h1;\k) {1;\k};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone have any pointers on how to modify the code?

Further, does anyone know how to mark the sides, like in the picture, and how to create a random-looking marking of the hexagons (although I this may have to simply be a lot of copying and pasting)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Could you show the community what you have tried so far? Posting a screenshot and asking folks to produce it from scratch may not receive much attention- posting an attempt and describing a specific detail that is holding you up may get more :)

Comment: There's some code for drawing [Chinese Checkers boards](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32302/chinese-checkers-board-using-tikz) that might come in handy here.

Comment: There's an excellent, very detailed article on [approaches to representing hexagonal grids](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/). Very insightful, with fun interactive graphics `=)`.

Comment: I've got to ask: Is this for tabletop RPG or wargaming by any chance?

Comment: No, I am writing an essay where I am, in one part, discussing the proof of Brouwer's fixed-point theorem using the board game Hex. The paper, by D. Gale, is called "The Game of Hex and the Brouwer Fixed-Point Theorem" in case you're interested in the proof!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[image]

This `MWE` with `Asymptote` uses `struct hexboard` from `hexboard.asy` module (attached).
The board `hb` is created with the command `hexboard hb=hexboard(11,xo);`
is `11` cells wide, the marks are prepared in the array of strings `string[] xo`;

Cell nodes and directions are as follows (direction is named after the node of destination):

[image]

The thick line is constructed by the start cell, optional prefix and suffix 
(if the line goes outside the grid), the node number to start with
and a sequence of the directions. For example a command

```
hb.oline((-10,0), prefix=(0,-1),3,4,5,0);
```

uses the node `3` of the bottom cell `(-10,0)` as a starting point,
prepends it with the line from below point `(0,-1)`
and continue with directions `4`,`5` and `0` (`4` segments in total).

Position of the leftmost cell is `(0,0)`, rightmost cell is `(n-1,0)`
the top is at `(0,n-1)`, and the bottom is at `(0,-(n-1))`.

```
%
% hexboard.tex :
%
\begin{filecontents*}{hexboard.asy}
struct hexboard{
  int n;
  string[] xo;
  string xmark,omark;
  real dx,dy;

  pen gridPen;
  pen xCellBg;
  pen oCellBg;

  guide ghex;

  pair hexCenter(int k, int j){ // k= +/-
    return ((j+abs(k)/2)*dx,k*dy);
  }

  pair hexCorner(int k, int j, int a){ 
    return shift(hexCenter(k,j))*point(ghex,a%6);
  }

  void dot(int k, int j, int a, pen p=gridPen){
    dot(hexCorner(k,j,a),p,UnFill);
  }

  void dots(int k, int j, int a, int b, pen p=gridPen){
    for(int i=a;i<=b;++i){
      dot(hexCorner(k,j,i),p,UnFill);
    }
  }

  void oline(explicit pair start, explicit pair prefix=(0,0), explicit pair suffix=(0,0), 
         explicit pen lpen=orange+2bp+opacity(0.8) ... int[]dirs){
    pair p=hexCorner((int)start.x,(int)start.y,dirs[0]);
    guide g=(p+prefix)--p;
    for(int i=1;i<dirs.length;++i){
      p+=dir(150+(dirs[i]%6)*60);
      g=g--p;
    }
    g=g--(p+suffix);
    draw(g,lpen);
  }

  void drawHex(int k, int j){
    pen bg=(substr(xo[n-1-k],j,1)=="x")?xCellBg:oCellBg;
    filldraw(shift((j+abs(k)/2)*dx,k*dy)*ghex,bg,gridPen);
  }

  void markCell(int k, int j, string v){
    if(v=="x")v=xmark;
    if(v=="o")v=omark;
    label(v,hexCenter(k,j));
  }

  void mark(){
    assert(xo.length==2n-1);
    bool b;
    string c;
    int k;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
      assert(length(xo[i])==i+1);
      k=n-1-i;
      for(int j=0;j<i+1;++j){
        c=substr(xo[i],j,1);
        drawHex(k,j);
        markCell(k,j,c);
      }
    }
    for(int i=n;i<2n-1;++i){
      assert(length(xo[i])==2n-1-i);
      k=n-1-i;
      for(int j=0;j<2n-1-i;++j){
        c=substr(xo[i],j,1);
        drawHex(k,j);
        markCell(k,j,c);
      }
    }
  }

  void operator init(int n // board width
      ,string[] xo         // board marks
      ,string xmark="$\times$"
      ,string omark="$\circ$"
      ,pen gridPen=deepblue+0.4bp
      ,pen xCellBg=palered
      ,pen oCellBg=palegreen
    ){
    this.n=n; 
    this.xo=copy(xo);
    this.xmark=xmark; this.omark=omark;
    this.xCellBg=xCellBg; this.oCellBg=oCellBg;
    this.dx=sqrt(3);
    this.dy=1+1/2;
    this.ghex=dir(90)--dir(150)--dir(210)--dir(270)--dir(330)--dir(30)--cycle;
    mark();
  }
}
\end{filecontents*}
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{asy}
size(10cm);

// === test hexboard
import hexboard;
string[] xo={
"o",
"xo",
"xxx",
"ooox",
"xxoox",
"xxoooo",
"oxxoxxo",
"xoxooxxx",
"oxooxooox",
"xooxooxooo",
"oxxxoxooxxo",
"oooxoxxoxx",
"xxxoxooxo",
"ooxooxxo",
"xxoooxo",
"ooxxxo",
"xoxoo",
"xoxx",
"oxo",
"xo",
"x",
};

hexboard hb=hexboard(11,xo);

label("$v$",hb.hexCorner(0,0,2)-(1,0),W);
label("$v^\prime$",hb.hexCorner(0,10,5)+(1,0),E);

label("$w$",hb.hexCorner(-10,0,3)-(0,1),S);
label("$w^\prime$",hb.hexCorner(10,0,0)+(0,1),N);

label("$o^\prime$",hb.hexCorner(5,0,1)-(1,0),W);
label("$x^-$",hb.hexCorner(5,5,5)+(1,0),E);

hb.oline((5,0),0,1,2,3,2,3,2,3,4,5,4,5,0,5, 4,5,0,1,0,1,2);
hb.oline((10,0), prefix=(0,1) ,suffix=(1,0)
,0
,3,2,3,2,1,0,5,0,1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,3,2,3,2,3,4
,3,2,3,2,1,0,5,0,1,0,1,2,3,2,3,4
,3,2,3,4
,3,4,3,2,3);

hb.oline((0,0), prefix=(-1,0),2,3,2,3,4);

hb.oline((-10,0), prefix=(0,-1),3,4,5,0);

hb.dot(9,0,3);
hb.dot(7,1,4);
hb.dots(5,1,0,3);

shipout(bbox(Fill(lightyellow)));

\end{asy}
\caption{Hex Board}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
%
% Process :
%
% pdflatex hexboard.tex    
% asy hexboard-*.asy    
% pdflatex hexboard.tex
```

Comment: One question, how do I make the figure larger? Preferably so that it fills the whole page.

Other than that, this worked perfectly, although the co-ordinates of the hexagons is confusing. Maybe it will make sense after I get some sleep, the co-ordinate system led to a huge guessing game but I got [the final product!](http://i.imgur.com/bxJAUYZ.png)

Comment: @Surculus: One way to scale the figure to fit the whole page
would be as follows: make it a `standalone` using `standalone` document class
(don't forget to remove the `figure` environment)
and then include it with `pdfpages` package. 
As for co-ordinates:
perhaps it would be less confusing with the edited picture:
direction is named after the node of destination.

Answer (score 24):

Here an approach different from my first approach.  It is similar in some ways to @g.kov 's approach but does not rely upon `Asymptote`.  Also, this approach figures out where the borders should be drawn merely by examining the contents of neighboring cells.

I've added a new macro `\sethexboardbaselength` which takes a dimension as an argument.  This macro can help you scale the hex-board to the size you want.

**UPDATE** I've added some garbage collection to remove and delete the macros holding cell information once the hex-board has been drawn.  Without doing this, if you draw boards of different sizes, later boards may mistake hold-over information from a previous board as information about the current board.  Also macros hold hex-board cell information are removed by `\let`ting them to an undefined control sequence `\ae@undefined@`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\makeatletter

\newlength{\hexagon@base@length}
\newlength{\x@base@length}
\newlength{\y@base@length}
\setlength{\hexagon@base@length}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\x@base@length}{\hexagon@base@length}
\setlength{\y@base@length}{\dimexpr2\hexagon@base@length\relax}
%% macro to set the dimensions for each hexagon, use this to change
%% the size of the hex-board
\def\sethexboardbaselength#1{%%
  \setlength{\hexagon@base@length}{\dimexpr#1\relax}
  \setlength{\x@base@length}{\hexagon@base@length}
  \setlength{\y@base@length}{\dimexpr2\hexagon@base@length\relax}
}
%% styles for the hexboard
\tikzset{
    my hexagonal node/.style={ 
      shape=regular polygon,
      regular polygon sides=6,
      minimum size=\y@base@length/sin(60),
      draw,
      inner sep=0,
      anchor=south,
      %%fill=#1,
      rotate=210,%%so ".corner 1" is at bottom of hexa shape
    },
  set hex board dimensions/.style={x=\x@base@length, y=\y@base@length*sin(60)},
  my hex path/.style={line width=3pt,line cap=round,blue},
}


%% some booleans to help keep track of where we are on the board
%% as we're drawing border.                                     
\newif\if@in@top@of@hex@board
\newif\if@at@hex@board@equator
\newif\if@at@row@initial@position

%% Since each row of the Hex Board is passed through      
%% a \foreach loop, it is safe to assume that there are   
%% no commas in a given row of the table.  So first time  
%% this macro is called, it should be called with trailing
%% commas.  We then know we're done with the current row  
%% once we've come across those commas.                   
\def\graph@current@row@of@hexagon#1#2#3\@nil{%%
  \@create@new@hexagon@cell{#1}
  \@build@borders@between@neighbors{#1}%%
  \@at@row@initial@positionfalse
  %% recursively call this macro if there are still elements left for the row
  \if,#2\relax
  \else
    \xdef\@cur@h@pos{\number\numexpr\@cur@h@pos+2\relax}
    \graph@current@row@of@hexagon#2#3\@nil
  \fi
}

%% Define a node for the current hex board cell                               
%% Each hex-cell on the board is given a node named as as                              
%%    H<current row>;<current horizontal position>                            
\def\@create@new@hexagon@cell#1{%%                                            
  %% define a node for the current position                                   
  %% Next three lines are just "fluff" to make "x" cells stand out.           
  \if#1x
    \node[my hexagonal node,fill=red!20] at (\@cur@h@pos,-\@cur@row) {};
  \fi
  %% (1) define a macro to hold the name of the "current" cell                
  %% (2) create the hexagonal cell for "current" cell                         
  %% (3) define a macro with which to "remember" cell content                 
  %% (4) define an easily called macro for "current" cell content.            
  \edef\ae@node@name{H\@cur@row;\@cur@h@pos}
  \node[my hexagonal node,label=center:#1] ({\ae@node@name}) at (\@cur@h@pos,-\@cur@row) {};
  \expandafter\xdef\csname ae@node\ae@node@name\endcsname{#1}
  \edef\ae@tmp@c{\csname ae@node\ae@node@name\endcsname}
  %% \typeout{NODE:={H\@cur@row;\@cur@h@pos}}
  %% collect names of macros used to store cell content info for 
  %% removal once the board has been completed.
  \ifx\relax\ae@garbage@
    \xdef\ae@garbage@{\ae@node@name}%%
  \else
    \xdef\ae@garbage@{\ae@garbage@,\ae@node@name}%%
  \fi
}

%% #1 = row                                                                                     
%% #2 = horizontal position within current row                                                  
%% #3 = name of cell we're loooking at: w=west, nw=north west, ne=north east                    
%% #4 = value to assume if@at@hex@board@equator:  ie, at border between TOP and BOTTOM of board 
%% #5 = value to assume if@in@top@of@hex@board AND in top half of board                         
%% #6 = value to assume if in BOTTOM                                                            
\def\@examine@adjacent@cell#1#2#3#4#5#6{%%                                                      
  \edef\@@ae@tmp@name{ae@nodeH\number\numexpr#1\relax;\number\numexpr#2\relax}
  \ifcsname\@@ae@tmp@name \endcsname
    \edef\@@ae@tmp@csname{\expandafter\csname\@@ae@tmp@name\endcsname}
  \else
    \if@at@hex@board@equator
      \edef\@@ae@tmp@csname{#4}%%
    \else
      \if@in@top@of@hex@board
        \edef\@@ae@tmp@csname{#5}%%
      \else
        \edef\@@ae@tmp@csname{#6}%%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \expandafter\edef\csname ae@tmp@#3\endcsname{\@@ae@tmp@csname}
  %% \typeout{ ___#4___ --> \csname ae@tmp@#4\endcsname\space <=> \ae@tmp@c}
}

%% This next macro examines the contents of the cells to the WEST, NORTH WEST, and NORTH EAST 
%% If the contents of those cells differ from the content of the "current" cell, draw a       
%% border between them.z                                                                      
%% Special conditions hold on the border of the board.  If there is no cell bordering a       
%% particular side of the "current" cell, then I make various assumptions which are handled   
%% by the macro \@examine@adjacent@cell:                                                      
%%   * on the board's north west side, non-existent cells are assumed to have content of "o"  
%%   * on the board's north east side, non-existent cells are assumed to have content of "x"  
%%   * on the board's south west side, non-existent cells are assumed to have content of "x"  
%%   * on the board's south east side, non-existent cells are assumed to have content of "o"  
%% The macro \@build@borders@for@last@row@entry handles similar cases for the last cell of    
%% each row.                                                                                  
\def\@build@borders@between@neighbors#1{%%                                                    
  %% (1) check to the "WEST"                                                                  
  %% (2) check to the "NORTH WEST"                                                            
  %% (3) check to the "NORTH EAST"                                                            
  \@examine@adjacent@cell{\@cur@row}{\@cur@h@pos-2}{w}{o}{o}{x}
  \@examine@adjacent@cell{\@cur@row-1}{\@cur@h@pos-1}{nw}{o}{o}{x}
  \@examine@adjacent@cell{\@cur@row-1}{\@cur@h@pos+1}{ne}{x}{x}{o}
  %% draw borders
  \if x\ae@tmp@c
    \if o\ae@tmp@w
      \draw[my hex path] (\ae@node@name.corner 6) -- (\ae@node@name.corner 5);
    \fi
    \if o\ae@tmp@nw
      \draw[my hex path] (\ae@node@name.corner 5) -- (\ae@node@name.corner 4);
    \fi
    \if o\ae@tmp@ne
      \draw[my hex path] (\ae@node@name.corner 4) -- (\ae@node@name.corner 3);
    \fi
  \fi
  \if o\ae@tmp@c
    \if x\ae@tmp@w
      \draw[my hex path] (\ae@node@name.corner 6) -- (\ae@node@name.corner 5);
    \fi
    \if x\ae@tmp@nw
      \draw[my hex path] (\ae@node@name.corner 5) -- (\ae@node@name.corner 4);
    \fi
    \if x\ae@tmp@ne
      \draw[my hex path] (\ae@node@name.corner 4) -- (\ae@node@name.corner 3);
    \fi
    \if@at@row@initial@position
      \if@in@top@of@hex@board
      \else
        \draw[my hex path] (\ae@node@name.corner 1) -- (\ae@node@name.corner 6);
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}

%% Cells to the EAST and SOUTH EAST need only be examined if you are 
%% currently in the last position of the current row.
\def\@build@borders@for@last@row@entry{%%
  \if x\ae@tmp@c
    \if@in@top@of@hex@board
    \else
      \draw[my hex path] (\ae@node@name.corner 1) -- (\ae@node@name.corner 2);
      \draw[my hex path] (\ae@node@name.corner 2) -- (\ae@node@name.corner 3);
    \fi
  \fi
  \if o\ae@tmp@c
    \if@in@top@of@hex@board
      \draw[my hex path] (\ae@node@name.corner 2) -- (\ae@node@name.corner 3);
    \fi
  \fi
}

%% Find out how many rows there are.  There should always be  
%% an odd number.  Add one to this number and divide by two.  
%% This new number determines whether you're in the top or the
%% bottom of the hex board.                                   
\def\@determine@widest@row#1{%% 
  \def\@width@at@hex@board@equator{0}%%
  \foreach \x in {#1}{\xdef\@width@at@hex@board@equator{\number\numexpr\@width@at@hex@board@equator+1\relax}}%%
  \edef\@width@at@hex@board@equator{\number\numexpr(\@width@at@hex@board@equator+1)/2\relax}
  %%\typeout {NUMBER OF ROWS -> \@width@at@hex@board@equator}
}

\def\@init@positions{%%
  \def\@cur@row{1}%%
  \def\@pseudo@row{1}%%
  \def\@cur@h@pos{0}}



%% In the following macro:                                                              
%%   @cur@row      counts the current row from 1 on up.                                 
%%   @pseudo@row   counts the current row until @cur@row==\@width@at@hex@board@equator  
%%                 and then starts to count down.  The value of this macro is used      
%%                 to help determine position the first hexagon of the current row.     
%%   @cur@h@pos    is initially set to the opposite of @pseudo@row, this value is       
%%                 the position of the first hexagon on the "current" row.              
\def\drawboard#1{%%
  \let\ae@garbage@\relax
  \@in@top@of@hex@boardtrue
  \@at@hex@board@equatorfalse
  \@determine@widest@row{#1}%%
  \@init@positions
  %%\typeout{ ============================================================ }
  %%\typeout{ NEW BOARD = }
  %%\typeout{ ============================================================ }
  \begin{tikzpicture}[set hex board dimensions]
    \foreach \hexbox in {#1}
      {
        \xdef\@cur@h@pos{-\@pseudo@row}
        \@at@row@initial@positiontrue
        \expandafter\graph@current@row@of@hexagon\hexbox,,\@nil
        \@build@borders@for@last@row@entry
        \global\@at@hex@board@equatorfalse
        \xdef\@cur@row{\number\numexpr\@cur@row+1}
        \if@in@top@of@hex@board
          \xdef\@pseudo@row{\number\numexpr\@pseudo@row+1}
          \ifnum\@pseudo@row=\@width@at@hex@board@equator\relax
            \global\@at@hex@board@equatortrue
            \global\@in@top@of@hex@boardfalse
          \fi
        \else
          \xdef\@pseudo@row{\number\numexpr\@pseudo@row-1\relax}
        \fi
        %%\typeout{ ------------------------------------------------------------------ }
      }
  \ae@dump@garbage
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

%% Remove macros storing information about contents of cells
\def\ae@dump@garbage{%%
  \foreach \ae@node@name in \ae@garbage@
    {\global\expandafter\let\csname ae@node\ae@node@name\endcsname\ae@undefined@}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\hspace*{\fill}
%%
\drawboard{
                          x     ,
                         o x    ,
                        x o x   ,
                       x x x x  ,
                        o x o   ,
                         o o    , 
                          x 
            }
%%
\hspace*{\fill}
%%
\drawboard{
                          x     ,
                         o x    ,
                        x o x   ,
                       x x x x  ,
                      x x o x x ,
                       o o x o  ,
                        o x o   ,
                         o o    , 
                          x 
            }
%%
\hspace*{\fill}


 \hspace*{\fill}
 \drawboard{
                           x      ,
                          o x     ,
                         x o x    ,
                        x o x o   ,
                       x o o x o  ,
                      x o x o x x ,
                       x o o x x  ,
                        o o x o   ,
                         o x o    ,
                          o x     , 
                           x 
             }
 \hspace*{\fill}

\pagebreak

OP's original board

\hspace*{\fill}
\drawboard{
                          o           ,   
                         x o          ,
                        x x x         ,
                       o o o x        ,
                      x x o o x       ,
                     x x o o o o      ,
                    o x x o x x o     ,
                   x o x o o x x x    ,
                  o x o o x o o o x   ,
                 x o o x o o x o o o  ,
                o x x x o x o o x x o ,
                 o o o x o x x o x x  ,
                  x x x o x o o x o   ,
                   o o x o o x x o    ,
                    x x o o o x o     ,
                     o o x x x o      ,
                      x o x o o       ,
                       x o x x        ,
                        o x o         ,
                         x o          ,
                          x                               
            }                          
\hspace*{\fill}

\hspace*{\fill}
\drawboard{
                          o           ,   
                         o x          ,
                        x o x         ,
                       x x x o        ,
                      x o o o o       ,
                     o x x x o o      ,
                    o o o o x o x     ,
                   o o x x o x o x    ,
                  o x x o x x o o x   ,
                 x o x o x o o x x o  ,
                o x o x o x o o x o o ,
                 o x o x o x x o x o  ,
                  o x o x o o x o x   ,
                   x o x o x x o x    ,
                    x x o x o o x     ,
                     o o o x o x      ,
                      x x x o x       ,
                       x o o x        ,
                        x x x         ,
                         o x          ,
                          o                               
            }                          
\hspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In particular, here's your originally posted board:

```
\hspace*{\fill}
\drawboard{
                          o           ,   
                         x o          ,
                        x x x         ,
                       o o o x        ,
                      x x o o x       ,
                     x x o o o o      ,
                    o x x o x x o     ,
                   x o x o o x x x    ,
                  o x o o x o o o x   ,
                 x o o x o o x o o o  ,
                o x x x o x o o x x o ,
                 o o o x o x x o x x  ,
                  x x x o x o o x o   ,
                   o o x o o x x o    ,
                    x x o o o x o     ,
                     o o x x x o      ,
                      x o x o o       ,
                       x o x x        ,
                        o x o         ,
                         x o          ,
                          x                               
            }                          
\hspace*{\fill}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, @A.Ellett, one question about the definition of "west, north west, and north east": If I want to define "east", is it something like `\@examine@adjacent@cell{\@cur@row}{\@cur@h@pos+2}{east}{o}{o}{o}`? This does not work, and I don't know where is wrong.

Comment: @Chris.Q What exactly do you mean by "not working"?  The way the code is written, the east side of the hexagon has been set already by the hexagons to the west.  So what might look like "not working" may in fact be overwritten by what's happening with the western hexagon.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @A.Ellett! The logic in your code (if I understand correctly) about "east" and "west" is based on the relativity of "east" and "west". However, I'm now modifying your code for a specific layout of "o" and "x", and need to draw certain paths passing the east side of a specific hexagon. For example, "the path should go through `(corner 4)--(corner 3)` of the hexagon "o" which has "x" in its east side. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Chris.Q sounds like you should post this as a question of its own.

Comment: Hi, @A.Ellett, I post the question here: [Drawing Hex Boards with specific boundary](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195519/drawing-hex-boards-with-specific-boundary). Could you please check it to see if you can help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

I modified some snippets from [Jake's answer about Chinese checkers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32312/4778) and from [Alain's answer about an hexagonal grid](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61434/4778). Using the node labeling you can draw thick lines in between. It's better to use the corners as references, like I did in this answer about [naming corners of a polygon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141678/4778), rather than the usual `north, east` because the polygons are rotated.

The corners go counter-clockwise. I don't know of any way to change this, and I didn't find any mention in the manual. This is how it goes:

[image: corners image]

Here is a picture of it with the node names printed in each one (you can use those to reference the nodes like I did in the code below).

Below there is an example of the line. I didn't do all of them because it's time consuming and I wanted just to show how it worked. When you want to remove the label from the nodes, delete this line `label=center:{\count-\n}`.

[image: full hex map image]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}

\tikzset{hexa/.style={shape=regular polygon,
                      regular polygon sides=6,
                      minimum size=1cm, 
                      draw,
                      inner sep=0mm,
                      outer sep=0mm,
                      anchor=south,
                      fill=white,
                      rotate=-30},
        hl/.style={line width=3pt,line cap=round} 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[x=9mm, y=5mm]

\foreach \m [count=\count] in {1,...,10,11,10,...,1}{
            \foreach \n in {1,...,\m}
                \node at ({(\n-\m/2)*sin(60)},{\count*.75})
                [hexa, 
                name=\count-\n,
                label=center:{\count-\n}] {};
                }

\draw[hl]   ($(1-1.corner 5)+(0,-1)$) -- (1-1.corner 5) -- (1-1.corner 6) -- 
            (1-1.corner 1) -- (1-1.corner 2) -- (2-2.corner 3) --
            (2-2.corner 2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15):

In this approach, not much effort has gone into how to specify the contents of the board (which is basically just a 11x11 rectangle with the coordinates transformed). The OP did suggest some randomness for the hexagon contents so I went for that as it is easier.

The main idea was to show a different (although not necessarily better) way of specifying the path using the `turtle` library from `PGF`. Ideas for the appearance and the path drawn are shamelessly pinched from g.kov's answer.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,turtle, topaths}

\def\s{1cm}

\tikzset{hexagon/.style={%
    shape=regular polygon,
    regular polygon sides=6,
    inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
    minimum size=\s,
    draw,
    shape border rotate=-30,
    #1\space hexagon/.try
},
    o hexagon/.style={fill=blue!20, 
      execute at begin node={\tikz\draw[thick, x=(0:\s/6), y=(90:\s/6)] circle [radius=1];}},
    x hexagon/.style={fill=red!20,
      execute at begin node={\tikz\draw[thick, x=(0:\s/6), y=(90:\s/6)] (-1,-1) -- (1,1) (-1,1) -- (1,-1);}},
    turtle path/.style={
        ultra thick,
        draw=orange,
        line cap=round,
        turtle={home,#1}
    },
    turtle/.cd, f/.style={forward=\s/2}, 
    r/.style={right=#1, f}, r/.default=60, 
    l/.style={left=#1, f}, l/.default=60]
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x in {1,...,11}
    \foreach \y [evaluate={\h=int(rnd*2) ? "o" : "x";}] in {1,...,11}
        \node [x=(60:\s*cos 30), y=(120:\s*cos 30), hexagon={\h}] at (\x, \y) (hexagon \x-\y) {};

\draw [shift=(hexagon 11-11), shift=(90:1)] node [above] {$u^\prime$}
    [turtle path={r=180,l,r,l,r,r,r,r,l,l,l,r,l,l,l,r,l,r,r,l,r,l,l,r,r,l,r,r,r,r,l,l,r,l,l,l,r,l,l,r,r,l,l,r,l,r,r,l,l=30}]
    node [right] {$c^\prime$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Mark, there is a minor typo. I think you would like to spell "g.kov" rather than "k.gov", who is the author of the accepted answer.

Comment: @Chris.Q (and not "Qhris.C" ;) quite right! It is now changed.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a slightly different approach from the others offered:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

%% styles for the hexboard
\tikzset{
    hexa/.style={ 
      shape=regular polygon,
      regular polygon sides=6,
      minimum size=1cm/sin(60),
      draw,
      inner sep=0,
      anchor=south,
      %%fill=#1,
      rotate=210,%%so ".corner 1" is at bottom of hexa shape
    },
  set hex board dimensions/.style={x=0.5cm, y=1cm*sin(60)},
  my hex path/.style={line width=2pt,line cap=round},
}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@surculus@shownodenames
\def\showmynodenames{\@surculus@shownodenamestrue}
\def\surculus@topcnt{4}
\def\surculus@botcnt{5}
\def\surculus@set@boardwidth#1{%%
  \def\surculus@botcnt{#1}%%
  \def\surculus@topcnt{\number\numexpr#1-1\relax}}

%% Here's a command to set up the board.  The argument 
%% is the width of widest row in the board
\def\drawhexboard#1{%%
  \surculus@set@boardwidth{#1}
  \tikzset{set hex board dimensions}
    \foreach \row in {1,...,\surculus@botcnt}{%
      \foreach \pos in {1,...,\row}
        {%%
          \node[hexa=red!20] (H\row;\pos) at (2*\pos-\row,\row) {};
          \if@surculus@shownodenames
            \node at (H\row;\pos) {\row;\pos};
          \fi
        }
    }
    \def\startcnt{\number\numexpr\surculus@botcnt+1\relax}
    \def\endcnt{\number\numexpr\surculus@topcnt+\surculus@botcnt\relax}
    \foreach \row in {\endcnt,...,\startcnt}{%
      \foreach \pos in {\endcnt,...,\row}{%
        \edef\surculus@rowpos{\number\numexpr\pos-\row+1\relax}
        \node[hexa=blue!10] (H\row;\surculus@rowpos) at (2*\pos-\row-2*\surculus@topcnt,\row) {};
        \if@surculus@shownodenames
          \node at (H\row;\surculus@rowpos) {\row;\surculus@rowpos};
        \fi
      }
    }
}

%% command to assist in drawing the path around the hexagons.
\def\drawhexpath(#1)#2{%%
    \let\surculus@previous\relax%%
    \foreach \x in {#2}
      { \ifx\relax\surculus@previous
          \xdef\surculus@previous{\x}%%
          %% for testing %% \node [circle,fill=red,inner sep=2pt] at (H#1.corner \x) {};
        \else
          \draw[my hex path]  (H#1.corner \surculus@previous) -- (H#1.corner \x);
          \xdef\surculus@previous{\x}%%
        \fi
    }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \showmynodenames%%<-- must precede the creation of the board if you want to see node names
    \drawhexboard{10}
    \draw[my hex path] ($(H1;1.corner 1)-(0,1cm)$) -- (H1;1.corner 1);
    \drawhexpath(1;1){1,2,3,4}
    \drawhexpath(2;2){6,5}
    \drawhexpath(3;2){1,2,3,4,5,6}
    \drawhexpath(3;1){2,1,6,5}
    \drawhexpath(4;1){1,2,3}
    \drawhexpath(5;2){1,2,3,4,5}

    \draw[my hex path] ($(H10;10.corner 3)+(1cm,0)$) -- (H10;10.corner 3);
    \drawhexpath(10;10){3,2,1,6,5}
    \drawhexpath(10;9){3,4}
    \drawhexpath(11;8){2,3,4}
    \drawhexpath(12;8){6,5,4,3,2}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The idea here is that `\drawhexboard{<num>}` creates a hex board with its widest row set to `<num>`.  You can then draw paths around individual cells using the command

```
\draw(<node id>){<comma separated list of corners>}
```

I created a command `\showmynodenames` which allows you to see the names of the nodes to help define the paths.  Just comment that line out and you'll get the hex diagram as you want it.

With `\showmynodenames` commented out, you get:

[image]

With `\showmynodenames` turned on, you get:

[image]

**To do**

Some work needs to be done to *smooth* out the connections along the path.  I'll have to work on that later though.

Also, it's possible to define a macro which will set the content of each hex-box to either `x` or `o`.  But, unfortunately, I don't have the time at this moment to write up that part of the code.  I'll look at it later in the day.

Answer (score 10):

Just for fun with PSTricks. It is not a complete solution.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-poly}
\psset{PstPicture=false,PolyRotation=30}

\def\Cell(#1,#2)#3{\rput(!3 sqrt #1 #2 2 mod 0 eq {} {.5 add} ifelse mul 1.5 #2 mul){\PstHexagon\rput(0,0){#3}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-7,-7)(8,7)
    \multido{\ix=-3+1}{7}{\multido{\iy=-3+1}{7}{\Cell(\ix,\iy){$(\ix,\iy)$}}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: We can reduce the file size by a factor of 2 if we can make each edge drawn just once. But the algorithm to draw becomes more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

The package [hexboard](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hexboard) (which I co-wrote) can do something like this.

> I need to draw a Hex board.

hexboard works within an environment called `hexpicture` (or `hexgame` if you'd like to include a sequence of moves). Here's the basic code to draw an 11x11 Hex board.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{hexboard}

\begin{document}
    \begin{hexpicture}
        \hexboard{11}
    \end{hexpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here's the result.

[image: Blank 11 by 11 Hex board]

> I would like to be able to mark each hexagon

hexboard has a command `\hexcontent{column}{row}{content}` which can be used to place any content inside a cell. `column` can be either the column letter (a-z) or the column number. `row` is the row number. `content` can in principle be anything, though there is limited room.

For example, this code draws a 5x5 board and labels cell c3 with an 'o' and cell c4 with an 'x'.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{hexboard}
\begin{document}
    \begin{hexpicture}
        \hexboard{5}
        \hexcontent{c}{3}{o}
        \hexcontent{c}{4}{x}
    \end{hexpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: 5x5 Hex board with cell c3 labelled 'o' and cell c4 labelled 'x'.]

There are lots of other labelling possibilities for cells. For example, using a similar syntax, you can:

- Shade cells e.g. shade cell c3 using `\hexcellshaded{c}{3}`. The default is yellow but alternative colours can be specified, e.g. shade cell f10 magenta using `\hexcellshaded[magenta]{f}{10}`.
- Draw a small dot in the middle of a cell, e.g. in cell b5 using `\hexdot{b}{5}`.
- place Hex counters on the board. Counters are placed for players A and B whose colours are customisable. For example, to place a counter for player A in cell d7 use `\hexcounter{d}{7}{A}`.
- draw lines between two cells, e.g. to draw a line from the centre of cell c1 to the centre of cell b2 use `\hexconnect{c}{1}{b}{2}`.

> Being able to control the thickness of the lines would be nice, but it is not something I need to have.

First, the size of the diagram is controlled by a command `\hexscale{size}`. The default is 2.

For example, here the same diagram is drawn at default scale (left) and using `\hexscale{5}` (right).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hexboard}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{hexpicture}
        \hexboard{3}
        \hexcounter{b}{2}{A}
        \hexcounter{a}{2}{B}
        \hexcounter{c}{1}{A}
        \hexcounter{b}{3}{B}
        \hexcounter{a}{3}{A}
    \end{hexpicture}

    \hexscale{5}

    \begin{hexpicture}
        \hexboard{3}
        \hexcounter{b}{2}{A}
        \hexcounter{a}{2}{B}
        \hexcounter{c}{1}{A}
        \hexcounter{b}{3}{B}
        \hexcounter{a}{3}{A}
    \end{hexpicture}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: Small Hex board and large Hex board]

Actually, what `\hexscale` does is enlarge the hexagons and control three line width parameters:

- `\hexlinewidth`: used for the standard edges of hexagons.
- `\hexedgewidth`: used for the thick coloured borders at the edge of the board.
- `\hexthinline`: used by `\hexconnect` to draw lines between cells.

These are just commands, so can be redefined if needed. The defaults are:

```
\newcommand{\hexlinewidth}{0.07}
\newcommand{\hexedgewidth}{0.15}
\newcommand{\hexthinline}{0.03}
```

So for example, this draws a standard sized board with slightly thicker regular lines and slightly thinner edge borders. These changes will be reset if `\hexscale` is used.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{hexboard}
\renewcommand{\hexlinewidth}{0.1}
\renewcommand{\hexedgewidth}{0.12}

\begin{document}
    \begin{hexpicture}
        \hexboard{3}
        \hexcounter{b}{2}{A}
    \end{hexpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Hex board with slightly thicker regular lines and slightly thinner edge borders]

The image in the question shows parts of the borders of some cells thicker than others. I had not anticipated this need so this is not in the package. However, the code needed is very similar to the code used to mark the coloured edges, and this can be adapted.

Here I define six commands to shade the six sides of a specified cell using the thicker line width used for the coloured edges, only in black. Hopefully the meanings of topleft, bottomright, etc. are obvious. Note that the cell reference does not need to be a cell that was actually drawn by `\hexboard`, so we can follow the borders off the edge of the board.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{hexboard}

% these commands are based on the code that draws the coloured edge borders in hexboard
% they draw the six parts of a cell border for the cell specified by the two arguments
\newcommand{\bottomrightcellborder}[2]{\hexcoord{#1}{#2}\draw[black,shift={(\xchor em,\ychor em)},line width=\hexedgewidth em,line cap=round] (0 em,-0.577350 em) -- (0.5 em,-0.288675 em);}
\newcommand{\bottomleftcellborder}[2]{\hexcoord{#1}{#2}\draw[black,shift={(\xchor em,\ychor em)},line width=\hexedgewidth em,line cap=round] (-0.5 em,-0.288675 em) -- (0 em,-0.577350 em);}
\newcommand{\toprightcellborder}[2]{\hexcoord{#1}{#2}\draw[black,shift={(\xchor em,\ychor em)},line width=\hexedgewidth em,line cap=round] (0 em,0.577350 em) -- (0.5 em,0.288675 em);}
\newcommand{\topleftcellborder}[2]{\hexcoord{#1}{#2}\draw[black,shift={(\xchor em,\ychor em)},line width=\hexedgewidth em,line cap=round] (-0.5 em,0.288675 em) -- (0 em,0.577350 em);}
\newcommand{\leftcellborder}[2]{\hexcoord{#1}{#2}\draw[black,shift={(\xchor em,\ychor em)},line width=\hexedgewidth em,line cap=round] (-0.5 em,-0.288675 em) -- (-0.5 em,0.288675 em);}
\newcommand{\rightcellborder}[2]{\hexcoord{#1}{#2}\draw[black,shift={(\xchor em,\ychor em)},line width=\hexedgewidth em,line cap=round] (0.5 em,-0.288675 em) -- (0.5 em,0.288675 em);}

\begin{document}
    \begin{hexpicture}
        \hexboard{3}
        \bottomleftcellborder{b}{1}
        \leftcellborder{b}{1}
        \topleftcellborder{b}{1}
        \toprightcellborder{b}{1}
        \bottomrightcellborder{b}{2}
        \rightcellborder{b}{2}
        \topleftcellborder{c}{2}
        \leftcellborder{c}{3}
        \topleftcellborder{c}{3}
        \leftcellborder{c}{4}
        \toprightcellborder{b}{4}
        \leftcellborder{b}{2}
        \bottomrightcellborder{a}{3}
    \end{hexpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's the result.

[image: Hex board with some cell edges marked with thicker lines]

> Further, does anyone know how to mark the sides, like in the picture

You can refer to cells that aren't drawn. Or in hexboard, a `hexpicture` environment is just a `tikzpicture` with extra bells, so you can use TikZ commands inside a `hexpicture`. It might help to know that the height of a cell is 2/sqrt(3) em which is approx. 1.1547 em. Here I draw a board with labels outside the board via both methods.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{hexboard}

\begin{document}
    \begin{hexpicture}
        \hexboard{3}
        
        % using \hexcontent to refer to cells that aren't drawn
        \hexcontent{3}{-1}{Hello}
        \hexcontent{f}{2}{\( \int_0^1 3x^2 \mathrm{d}x \)}
        
        % using TikZ
        \node at (3.5 em,4 em) {TikZ}; 
        \node at (-1.5 em,2.3 em) {\( e^{i\pi}+1=0 \)}; 
    \end{hexpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image: Hex board with labels: above, "TikZ"; below, "Hello"; left, Euler's identity; right, integral from 0 to 1 of 3x squared with respect to x.]

> how to create a random-looking marking of the hexagons

Here's a way using TikZ/PGF random selection. The PGF command `\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist` declares the options. The two `\foreach` commands loop over the whole board. Then `\hexcontent` from hexboard is used to place a random item from the list using PGF command `\pgfmathrandomitem`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{hexboard}

\begin{document}
    \begin{hexpicture}
        \hexgrid{3}{4} % just to show an irregular board
        
        \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{choices}{{x}{o}}
        \foreach \x in {a,b,c} {
            \foreach \y in {1,2,3,4} {
                \hexcontent{\x}{\y}{\pgfmathrandomitem{\n}{choices}\n}
            }
        }
    \end{hexpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is something like this:

[image]