# A0 Hexagon background tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I’ve been looking for a template for a background of hexagons using tikz. Tinkering around with other designs have been not working out for me, so I thought I’d ask myself.

The main point for my request is to ask:

- for a **scalable** design,
- to be able to change the `sizes` of the hexagons some way,
- perhaps to **locate** specific hexagons fairly easily, or at all?

I’m looking for this on an `a0` poster but any help in the right direction would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Hexagon lattices can be found in several posts here, such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141911/121799.

Comment: You could also look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6019/1952

Answer (score 2):

To make hexagonal paving, I wrote a double foreach loop that makes a hexagonal paving from a minimal pattern.

This pattern is called `hexapavage` *(it is not a hexagon)*, it has the advantage of not drawing the same line twice and therefore, there is no superposition of lines between them.

[image: hexapavage]

```
\def\hexapavage{--++(60:1)--+(120:1)++(0,0)--++(1,0)--++(60:1)--+(1,0)++(-120:1)--++(-60:1)}
\tikz\draw[blue](0,0)\hexapavage;
```

I coloured a copy of this pattern in **blue** as well as a reduction of the hexagons in the second figure.

On the other hand, I didn't try to create a coordinate system to locate hexagons.

[image: pavage hexagonal]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone} 
\def\hexapavage{--++(60:1)--+(120:1)++(0,0)--++(1,0)--++(60:1)--+(1,0)++(-120:1)--++(-60:1)}

\begin{document} 

%\tikz\draw[blue](0,0)\hexapavage;
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Le pavage hexagonal
  \foreach \j in {0,1,...,4} {
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,4} {\draw[thick] (60:\j)++(120:\j)++
(60:\i)++(-60:\i)++(\i,0)++(\i,0) \hexapavage ;
}}
 \draw[blue,very thick](0,0)\hexapavage;

% pavage avec scale
 \begin{scope}[yshift=-6cm,scale=.6]
  \foreach \j in {0,1,...,4} {
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,4} {\draw[thick] (60:\j)++(120:\j)++
(60:\i)++(-60:\i)++(\i,0)++(\i,0) \hexapavage ;
}}
 \draw[blue,very thick](0,0)\hexapavage;
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh wow, `\draw[thick] (60:\j)++(120:\j)++
(60:\i)++(-60:\i)++(\i,0)++(\i,0) \hexapavage;` instead of  `\draw[thick] (3*\i,{sqrt(3)*\j}) \hexapavage;`...

Comment: This time, the text of your code is shorter. But at execution, they are both equally fast.

Comment: The compilation time is not the issue. The issue is that there is no reason to represent a translation by `\i` times something and `\j` times something by a zigzag combination with 6 steps. You know that the issue is not the compilation time, which is tiny. I stop here.

Comment: You're on the wrong track. I wrote this code two weeks after learning LaTeX during a professional training internship.