# Alignment of node labels in tikz-qtree

Tags: trees, tikz-qtree

I am trying to draw a refutation tree:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-qtree} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
     \Tree  
        [.\node[label= {$\langle \texttt{stateA(X)}, 0 \rangle$}] {};    
       [.\node[label= {$\langle \texttt{stateB(X, Y)}, 0 \rangle$}] {};   
            \edge node[left] {$X=a, Y=b$}; [.\node[label={$\langle \texttt{stateC(a,b)}, 0 \rangle$}]  {};   
                 \node[ label=below: {$\langle [], res1 \rangle$}] {};  
                 ]  
            \edge node[right] {$X=a, Y=c$}; [.\node[label={$\langle \texttt{stateD(b, c)}, 0 \rangle$}]  {};  
                 \node[ label=below: {$\langle [], res2 \rangle$}] {};  
                  ]   ]   ] 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Hovewer, in the resulting tree most labels are not in the right place. How can I possibly fix this?

Initially, I was experimenting with style definitions from [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39103/how-to-change-the-level-distance-in-tikz-qtree-for-one-level-only) but circles or rectangles do not seem to be a fit.

Comment: I think you place what should be the node contain within a label. Try to replace `\node[label= {$\langle \texttt{stateA(X)}, 0 \rangle$}] {};` with `\node {$\langle \texttt{stateA(X)}, 0 \rangle$};` and similar replacements for the rest of your tree.

Comment: Thanks, it is much better this way! Edge labels still looked out of place, so I had to quick-fix this `\edge node[left] {$X=a, Y=b$}; ` with this `\edge node[left] {\small{$X=a$; ~ $Y=b$} ~~~~~~~~~~};` (ugly but still working...)

Comment: I have also added spacing parameters: `\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=25mm, level distance=40pt]` Seems to be solved!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few  comments about your tree.

- It's generally never necessary to use explicit `\node` commands with `tikz-qtree` since each `[.label  ]` constituent label is automatically a node.
- To label an edge of a tree, you should use the `[auto=left]` and `[auto=right]` parameters for the node. This will ensure better placement of the label text.
- When making complicated node labels, your tree will be much more readable if you create some sensible markup for the different components of it.

Here's a version of your tree taking all these ideas into account:

I've created a `\brk` command to wrap something in angle brackets.  I've also created a `\state` command that puts its argument in `\texttt`. This way if you decide to change that formatting decision down the line you only need to change one command.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-qtree} 
\newcommand\state[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand\brk[1]{$\langle #1 \rangle$}
\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=40pt,sibling distance=25mm] 
  \Tree  
     [.{\brk{ \state{stateA(X)}, 0 }}   
        [.{\brk{ \state{stateB(X, Y)}, 0 }}  
            \edge node[auto=right] {$X=a, Y=b$}; 
            [.{\brk{ \state{stateC(a,b)}, 0 }}   
                 [.{\brk{ [], res1 }} ]  
                 ]  
            \edge node[auto=left] {$X=a, Y=c$}; [.{\brk{ \state{stateD(b, c)}, 0 }}  
                 [.{\brk{ [], res2 }} ]  
                  ]   ]   ] 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]