# Tikzmark between syntactic tree and matrix?

Tags: nodes, linguistics, tikz-qtree, tikzmark

I am trying to draw a line between the S node and the matrix, but have not been able to get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}


\usepackage{fontspec,tikz, tikz-qtree, multicol,avm,array}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, trees, calc, arrows, fit,tikzmark,positioning}

\begin{document}


\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\Tree [.\tikzmark{S}{S} [.NP [.Det the ]
[.N cat ] ]
[.VP [.V sat ]
[.PP [.P on ]
[.NP [.Det the ]
[.N; mat ] ] ] ] ]
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\columnbreak

\begin{avm}
\scriptsize
\[{} \tikzmark{PRED}{PRED} `avoid <SUBJ, OBJ>'; TNS $\neq$ PAST \cr
      TOPIC \[ PRED `kind<COMP>' \cr
                    DEF +; LOC FAR; NUM SG \cr
                    COMP \[ PRED `of <OBJ>' \cr
                            OBJ \[ PRED `cake'\] \] \]\tikzmark{topic} \cr
     SUBJ \[ PRED `pro'; NUM SG; PERS 1; CASE NOM\] \cr
      OBJ \[ $\qquad$ \]\tikzmark{object} \cr
     ADJ \[ PRED `usually'\] \]
\end{avm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
    \draw[->] (pic cs:S)--(pic cs:PRED);
    \draw[-] (pic cs:topic) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=2]  (pic cs:object);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. Instead, edit your original question to include the additional information. I've marked your other question as a potential duplicate but this is messy: this one should be the duplicate as it is newer, but it is also a much better question and now has an answer. So... Not sure what to do with it. Perhaps you could delete your other question? [Note that editing a question moves it back to the top of the front page of the site i.e. top of the queue of active questions. So you don't need to ask a new one to ensure it gets attention.]

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219008/tikz-qtree-for-connecting-syntactic-trees-and-lfg-feature-matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way that `tikz-qtree` works.  The long explanation can be found at [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55048/86) to [\draw alignment when connecting nodes using tikz-qtree, getting line centered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54118/86)

Cutting-and-pasting my code from that answer is half of the solution here.  The other half is to remove the `\tikzmark` from the tree.  Unfortunately, `\tikzmark` suffers from the same problem as the `tikz-qtree` (as explained in that answer) so it would need a similar adjustment.  Fortunately, this isn't necessary.  Since a `tikz-qtree` is inside a `tikzpicture` environment, we can use the ordinary `tikz` node labelling system to refer to nodes in a `tikzpicture`.  (`tikzmark` was developed for *outside* a `tikzpicture` and actually shouldn't be used inside as it then suffers from the [nested tikzpicture syndrom](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46598/86).)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219072/86}

\usepackage{fontspec,tikz, tikz-qtree, multicol,avm,array}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, trees, calc, arrows, fit,tikzmark,positioning}
\makeatletter

\def\unwind@subpic#1{%
% is #1 the current picture?
\edef\subpicid{#1}%
\ifx\subpicid\pgfpictureid
% yes, we're done
\else
% does #1 have a parent picture?
\expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@sh@pi@#1\endcsname\relax
% no, the original node was not inside the current picture
\pgf@xa=\pgf@x
\pgf@ya=\pgf@y
\pgfsys@getposition{\pgfpictureid}\pgf@shape@current@pos
\pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\pgf@shape@current@pos}%
\advance\pgf@xa by-\pgf@x%
\advance\pgf@ya by-\pgf@y%
\pgf@process{\pgfpointorigin\subpic@parent@pos}%
\advance\pgf@xa by \pgf@x%
\advance\pgf@ya by \pgf@y%
\pgf@x=\pgf@xa
\pgf@y=\pgf@ya
\else
% yes, apply transform, save picture location, and move up to parent picture
\pgfsys@getposition{\csname pgf@sh@pi@#1\endcsname}\subpic@parent@pos%
{%
  \pgfsettransform{\csname pgf@sh@nt@#1\endcsname}%
  \pgf@pos@transform{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}%
  \global\pgf@x=\pgf@x
  \global\pgf@y=\pgf@y
}%
\unwind@subpic{\csname pgf@sh@pi@#1\endcsname}%
\fi
\fi
}


\def\pgf@shape@interpictureshift#1{%
\def\subpic@parent@pos{\pgfpointorigin}%
\unwind@subpic{\csname pgf@sh@pi@#1\endcsname}%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}


\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\begin{scope}
\Tree [. \node (S) {S}; [.NP [.Det the ]
[.N cat ] ]
[.VP [.V sat ]
[.PP [.P on ]
[.NP [.Det the ]
[.N; mat ] ] ] ] ]
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\columnbreak

\begin{avm}
\scriptsize
\[{} \tikzmark{PRED}{PRED} `avoid <SUBJ, OBJ>'; TNS $\neq$ PAST \cr
      TOPIC \[ PRED `kind<COMP>' \cr
                    DEF +; LOC FAR; NUM SG \cr
                    COMP \[ PRED `of <OBJ>' \cr
                            OBJ \[ PRED `cake'\] \] \]\tikzmark{topic} \cr
     SUBJ \[ PRED `pro'; NUM SG; PERS 1; CASE NOM\] \cr
      OBJ \[ $\qquad$ \]\tikzmark{object} \cr
     ADJ \[ PRED `usually'\] \]
\end{avm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
\draw[->] (S)--(pic cs:PRED);
    \draw[-] (pic cs:topic) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=2]  (pic cs:object);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works after you switch to pdfLaTeX. For this, it's required to remove `fontspec` from the loaded packages.

With XeLaTeX I noticed the issue persisting.

Comment: Is there any way to solve this problem without losing fontspec, which I need for polyglossia?

Comment: @PRQ Would `babel` instead of `polyglossia` be an option?

Comment: @PRQ Have you tried LuaLaTeX? (Or `babel` as Stefan Kottwitz suggested.)

Comment: I need to be able to input Greek characters, and babel requires too much work given the number of sentence I need to input. I have never tried LuaLaTeX, but will look into it.