# Drawing a tree with text on the edge concisely using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I am new to TikZ and am trying to draw a tree with text only on the edge (action/line). I have managed to do it as seen below but I was hoping there was a more concise/legible way.

[image: Image produced]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}

\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=1cm, sibling distance=2.5cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=1cm, sibling distance=2.5cm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=1cm, sibling distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{level 4}=[level distance=1cm, sibling distance=2cm]

\tikzstyle{circleNode}=[circle,draw]
\tikzstyle{dotNode} = [circle, minimum width=3pt,fill, inner sep=0pt]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [dotNode] {}
child{
        node [dotNode] {}
    child{
        node [dotNode] {}
        child{
            node [dotNode] {}
                            child{
                                node [dotNode] {}
                                child{
                                    node [dotNode] {}
                                    child{
                                        node [dotNode] {}
                                        child{
                                            node [dotNode] {}
                                            child{
                                                node [dotNode] {}
                                                child{
                                                    node [dotNode] {}
                                                    edge from parent
                                                    node[left]{j}
                                                }
                                                edge from parent
                                                node[left]{$\tau$*}
                                            }
                                            edge from parent
                                            node[left]{b}
                                        }
                                        edge from parent
                                        node[left]{$\tau$*}
                                    }
                                    edge from parent
                                    node[left]{b}
                                }
                                child{
                                    node [dotNode] {}
                                    child{
                                        node [dotNode] {}
                                        child{
                                            node [dotNode] {}
                                            child{
                                                node [dotNode] {}
                                                child{
                                                    node [dotNode] {}
                                                    edge from parent
                                                    node[right]{k}
                                                }
                                                edge from parent
                                                node[right]{$\tau$*}
                                            }
                                            edge from parent
                                            node[right]{b}
                                        }
                                        edge from parent
                                        node[right]{$\tau$*}
                                    }
                                    edge from parent
                                    node[right]{b}
                                }
                                edge from parent
                                node[left]{$\tau$*}
                            }
            edge from parent
            node[left]{a}
        }
                    edge from parent
                    node[left]{$\tau$*}
    }
            edge from parent
            node[left]{a}
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384)

Comment: Check out the keys `auto` and `swap`. That is a proper way to place the nodes. Also you could introduce a `insert path` style that inserts `edge from parent node[<option>]{<content>}` in a shorter form, e.g. `[n={swap}{$\tau$}]`.

Comment: From what I've read I should use `[auto]` and `[auto, swap]` instead of `[left]` and `[right]`? I'm still looking at resources on how to use `insert path` properly as I've only found specific examples on different TikZ types, not on trees.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could check out my tikz-based tree-drawing package `forest`. The gallery in the documentation includes a style for easy drawing of decision trees (inspired by question [How to change the level distance in tikz-qtree for one level only?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39103/how-to-change-the-level-distance-in-tikz-qtree-for-one-level-only) on this site).

I have just generalized the style a bit and posted it to the `forest` [style repository](https://github.com/sasozivanovic/forest-styles).  Using the style-package `forest-decisiontree`, you could draw your tree like this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{forest-decisiontree}    
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} decision tree={3em}{8ex}{2pt}
  [[;a[;\tau^*[;a[;\tau^*
   [;b[;\tau^*[;b[;\tau^*[;j]]]]]
   [;b[;\tau^*,for tree={decision on right}
     [;b[;\tau^*[;k]]]]]
  ]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! For anyone who wants to use this you also need forest.sty (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest) which you unpack using the instructions here (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installing_Extra_Packages#Downloading_packages).

Comment: One more thing please, is there a way to include color in some of the text (but not all of the node) example `[;\tau \color{blue}{test} ]` but that's not compiling.

Comment: I was a bit careless when designing the style, so the content got expanded too soon (macros `\getfirst` and `\getsecond` were the culprits). Fixed (by adding `\unexpanded`) and uploaded. Now your example should work.