# How to list all known pgfkeys?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

Is there a way to list all known pgfkeys (i.e., those that are currently set)?

Concretely, I'm looking for a way to get the value of the tikz `scale` option. I was hoping there would be a pgfkey for that. But it seems more useful to ask the general question of listing all pgfkeys.

Comment: `\pgfkeysvalueof`?

Comment: @Manuel the problem is that I don't know the key I'm looking for. I'd like to list *all* keys and their values. The idea was to set `scale=5`, list all keys and search for `5`, to see if there's a key set to the scale.

Comment: *Concretely, I'm looking for a way to get the value of the tikz `scale` option…* I thought you knew :) I don't understand what you want.

Comment: @Manuel I want to get a list of all pgfkeys that are currently in the tree. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I don't know that, but may be you could hack at the correct place and make TikZ add the data to an array every time it sets a key.

Comment: Highly related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34712/how-do-i-debug-pgfkeys.

Comment: There is a difficulty tracing pgfkeys. Some keys, `scale`/`xsacle`/`yscale` for instance, share the similar purpose. And even worse, the effect of scaling and shifting is mixed, accumulated and handled by lower-level registers. So what do you exactly want?

Comment: @Symbol1 thanks for that link. To be honest, I solved my actual problem in a different way, without needing any key. I'm not sure what to do with this question now. It's not a duplicate of the one you linked to -- should we leave this question open or just delete it?